# Flutter - FutureBuilder works well on Android but not well on iOS

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, future

I implemented the **FutureBuilder** with the code below in order to get the distance from the user and the item that he wants buy but I get a **weird result between Android and iOS**.

On **Android** works well and I get the distance for each item.
But on **iOS** I don't have the distance for each item and infact some item has the distance and some items get null value.

[image]

```
class ProductHorizontalListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductHorizontalListItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    required this.coreTagKey,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  final Function? onTap;
  final String coreTagKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PsValueHolder valueHolder =
    Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(context, listen: false);

    Future<double> getCurrentLocation() async {
          Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
          double lat = position.latitude;
          double long = position.longitude;
          final double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
            double.parse(position.latitude.toString()),
            double.parse(position.longitude.toString()),
            double.parse(product.itemLocation!.lat.toString()),
            double.parse(product.itemLocation!.lng.toString()),
          );

            return Future.value(distanceInMeters);

        }

        return FutureBuilder<double>(
                future: getCurrentLocation(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
        return InkWell(
        onTap: onTap as void Function()?,
        child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: PsDimens.space4, right: PsDimens.space4,
                bottom: PsDimens.space12),
            child: Text(
                '${snapshot.data}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                    color: PsColors.textColor3
                )))

        );});
  }
}
```

I also tried to handle the states of FutureBuilder in each way but nothing.

iOS works bad, why?

I'm on Flutter 3.0.5 with Android Studio Chipmunk.

---

**UPDATE CODE WITH STATE MANAGEMENT**

```
class ProductHorizontalListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductHorizontalListItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    required this.coreTagKey,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Product product;
  final Function? onTap;
  final String coreTagKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PsValueHolder valueHolder =
    Provider.of<PsValueHolder>(context, listen: false);

    Future<double> getCurrentLocation() async {
          Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
          double lat = position.latitude;
          double long = position.longitude;
          final double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
            double.parse(position.latitude.toString()),
            double.parse(position.longitude.toString()),
            double.parse(product.itemLocation!.lat.toString()),
            double.parse(product.itemLocation!.lng.toString()),
          );

            return Future.value(distanceInMeters);

        }

        return FutureBuilder<double>(
                future: getCurrentLocation(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
            print(snapshot);
        if (snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting) {
           return const Text('Loading...');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
            return InkWell(
            onTap: onTap as void Function()?,
            child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: PsDimens.space4, right: PsDimens.space4,
                bottom: PsDimens.space12),
            child: Text(
                '${snapshot.data}',
                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                    color: PsColors.textColor3
                )))

        );}
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Error');
                                  }
            return Container();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

With state management, instead of null some item are stuck on "Loading..."

Comment: what do you see if you `print(snapshot)`?

Comment: @pskink the stranger thing is that when I scroll untill the end and I come back to top again the distance value is showed and there isn't null anymore.
Any ideas?

Comment: what does `print(snapshot)` show?

Comment: @pskink for some item is `AsyncSnapshot<double>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)`, for other is `AsyncSnapshot<double>(ConnectionState.waiting, 474775.89637660584, null, null)` and in the end for other `AsyncSnapshot<double>(ConnectionState.done, 474775.89637660584, null, null)`

Comment: @pskink Yes, are meters. After my question, in my code I added also `final double distanceInKilometers = distanceInMeters/1000;
    final double distanceInKilometersRounded = double.parse(distanceInKilometers.toStringAsExponential(2));`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should check the snapshot state before accessing its data. Otherwise you can get a null value, since the treatment has not been finished yet. Check `snapshot.connectionState` and `snapshot.hasData` before accessing `snapshot.data`.

Then, there is no need to convert latitudes and longitudes to String, then back to double.

Eventually, you can replace the definition of `final Function? onTap;` by a `VoidCallback`, to avoid parsing it in the Inkwell button.

Try this out:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Future<double> getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    final double distanceInMeters = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
      position.latitude,
      position.longitude,
      product.itemLocation!.latitude,
      product.itemLocation!.longitude,
    );
    return Future.value(distanceInMeters);
  }

  return FutureBuilder<double>(
    future: getCurrentLocation(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: PsDimens.space4,
              right: PsDimens.space4,
              bottom: PsDimens.space12,
            ),
            child: Text(
              '${snapshot.data}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                    color: PsColors.textColor3,
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        // Handle error case
        return const Text('error');
      } else {
        // Display a loader or whatever to wait for the Future to complete
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
  );
}
```

I tried the code by replacing position and product.itemLocation by location of actual cities, and the distanceInMeters is correct.

Comment: I follow your advice but it's same. On Android it's perfect but not on iOS.
My snapshot when I run iPhone emulator are for some item is `AsyncSnapshot<double>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)`, for other is `AsyncSnapshot<double>(ConnectionState.waiting, 474775.89637660584, null, null)` and in the end for other `AsyncSnapshot<double>(ConnectionState.done, 474775.89637660584, null, null)`

Comment: You should not handle the data if the connectionState is still waiting.
Did you add the `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData)` condition ?

Comment: Yes, I think I tried every kind of condition. The problem it seems not related to state because if I scroll my horizontal list of item and I come back to top then the distance appears on some item. But I don't understand why on Android it's all fine and not on iOS :(

Comment: From what you pasted in the previous comment, when getting null value you have ConnectionState.waiting. 
If after scrolling you get the result, it may be because the widget is then rebuild and the ConnectionState is done, thus you get the result.
The difference with Android could be the duration of treatment: the getCurrentPosition may be faster on Android, thus when building the widget, the ConnectionState is already done.

Can you paste the updated code with the check of ConnectionState?

Comment: I updated my question with the updated code with state management. With state management, instead of null some item are stuck on "Loading..."

Comment: I tried the updated code, it works fine. If you could provide a complete reproducible example (without external dependencies), so that I can launch it on iOS as well, I could help you better :-)

Comment: If I comment `Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();` and I provide custom position the function works well on iOS also.
So the problem is the geolocator. Pheraps I called it too many times?